# Package for getting location values in Tizen

Tags: c, linux, gps, gpsd, tizen

Which package in [Tizen](https://www.tizen.org/) is used to get the value of longitude and latitude? In the Tizen source there are many packages like geoclue, gpsmanager and libslp-location having many functions for getting GPS values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Geoclue. It has many providers like gpsd, manual etc. In those providers Nominatim gave me necessary values for Location.